# How can I get total of an order with DataWeave in Mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have the following scenario and problem. I receive a CSV file and need to map it with DataWeave, grouping by column "PON". I need to get the total of the order multiply this column ( Qty * Price ). I'm not getting the correct result:

CSV Data:

```
PON,Item,Qty,Price
PON1000,2015,2,38.08
PON1000,2016,1,33.37
PON1001,2015,2,38.08
```

DataWeave script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload groupBy ($.PON) pluck $ map ( () -> {
   "order": $[0].PON default "",
   "total": (sum( $.Price filter ($ != "") ) as Number) as String {format: "##,###.00"},
   "products": $ map {
       "product": $.Item,
       "price": ($.Price as Number) as String {format: "##,###.00"},
       "quantity": $.Qty
   }
})
```

Actual Result:

```
[
 {
   "order": "PON1000",
   "total": "71.45",
   "products": [
    {
     "product": "2015",
     "price": "38.08",
     "quantity": "2"
    },
    {
     "product": "2016",
     "price": "33.37",
     "quantity": "1"
    }
   ]
   },
   {
    "order": "PON1001",
    "total": "38.08",
    "products": [
    {
      "product": "2015",
       "price": "38.08",
       "quantity": "2"
     }
    ]
    }
   ]
```

I need to to multiply by order the `price` * `quantity` correpondent and finally sum that value and put it in the column `total` ordered by `order`.

Expected Result:

```
[
 {
   "order": "PON1000",
   "total": "109.53",
   "products": [
    {
     "product": "2015",
     "price": "38.08",
     "quantity": "2"
    },
    {
     "product": "2016",
     "price": "33.37",
     "quantity": "1"
    }
   ]
   },
   {
    "order": "PON1001",
    "total": "76.16",
    "products": [
    {
      "product": "2015",
       "price": "38.08",
       "quantity": "2"
     }
    ]
    }
   ]
```

Comment: Your obtained and expected result should be updated to show the quantity as 1 instead of 2 for product 2015.

Answer (score 2):

I just added two things:

1. For the total I used `Arrays::sumBy` which let's you do an operation on each item and the it sums all the results.
2. I infered from your code you expect the price to be empty, so I created safeNumber() to check that and return 0 in case it's empty (default did not work).

This is the code I've got so far:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
fun safeNumber(str) = if(isEmpty(str)) 0 else str as Number
---
payload groupBy ($.PON) pluck $ map ( () -> {
   "order": $[0].PON default "",
   "total": ($ sumBy( (i) -> safeNumber(i.Qty) * safeNumber(i.Price))) as String {format: "##,##0.00"},
   "products": $ map {
       "product": $.Item,
       "price": safeNumber($.Price) as String {format: "##,##0.00"},
       "quantity": $.Qty
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Below script will help you.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import divideBy from dw::core::Objects

---
payload groupBy $.PON  mapObject ((value, key, index) -> 
({
   order: (key),
   total: sum(value map ($.Qty  * $.Price)),
   value : value
})
) divideBy 3
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following DataWeave expression:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload groupBy $.PON pluck $ map (() -> {
    "order": $[0].PON,
   "total": sum($ map ($.Qty as Number * $.Price as Number)),
   "products": $ map { 
       "product": $.Item,
       "price": $.Price as Number,
       "quantity": $.Qty as Number
    }
})
```